# NSLayoutConstraints update after first tableview presentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

1. I load a custom `UITableViewCell` from a xib
2. I update a `NSLayoutConstraint` programmatically in
   `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Autolayout and manual change of `NSLayoutConstraint` works as it should - device size, orientation etc.

BUT: on the very FIRST presentation of the cell the programmatic changes are not displayed.
Changing views and going back updates as expected.

I believe I need to put `[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` somewhere.
I tried all kinds of places (`viewDidAppear, didEndDisplayingCell ...`)

Where should this go?

Could it be a new cell / reused cell issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already updated (modified) a constraint, so the view doesn't need to have its constraints updated. What it needs is to have its layout updated in response to the constraint change. So, I think you need to do `[view setNeedsLayout]`. It should be done on the view to which the constraint was added (or the common ancestor view of all views involved in the constraint which is modified). It should be done in the same code which modifies the constraint, just after modifying it.

That said, I'm not sure that `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a good place for attempting to modify a constraint for the view being returned. At that point, the cell view has not been added as a subview of the table. Constraints can only be added for views in the same view hierarchy.

Comment: You're right, I moved the constraint modification to the view itself (see comment below) and cornered the problem...

Answer (score 2):

So, to sum things up - this is what I did in order to get nicely laid out views every time:

The UIView is now responsible for itself, no messing around in the tableviewController.

I did not need to call (void)updateConstraints anywhere which makes sense since I set up the constraints in IB and just added a property to be able to change a constant. The actual constraints were left untouched and just needed layout!

1. Moved all layout code to my UITableViewCell subclass, named it (void)updateMedian (just two lines of code).
2. Made a property to pass information (a basic float) needed for recalculation of label position into subclass.
3. Used (void)updateMedian in (void)layoutSubviews of the UITableViewCell subclass to update my coordinates.
4. Also added a call to (void)updateMedian and [self layoutIfNeeded] in (void)prepareForReuse in my subclass.
5. Added [cell setNeedsLayout]; [cell layoutIfNeeded] in cellForRowAtIndexPath in my tableviewController.

I guess, the last step makes for a little redundancy. But otherwise there were still some cells that were displaying incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and call `setNeedsLayout` in `awakeFromNib:`.

You can also move updating constraints to the cell's `updateConstraints` method, making your `UITableViewController` a bit smaller. After all, a cell is a separate `UIView` and it should know how to layout itself, not the table view controller.

Comment: I did subclass UITableViewCell already. Your suggestion to move the code to the actual view makes perfect sense. While doing that I discovered the actual problem: my constraint calculation depends on a label's frame.width. The label's text is set in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: So, this is what happens: 1) new cell: updateConstraints gets called - wrong label.width  2) cell reuse: prepareForReuse - correct label.width. Will try some more and report back!

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I am getting is like

If you can have provided constraints to the object from storyboard using pin then it will set those constraints to the object and if you have added constraint programatically in “cellForRowAtIndexPath:” it will over-right the constraints which you had set in story board. You might have set them only for single cell by mistake so it might be displaying effect in single cell.

Can you please try following solution and check if it help you. Put this code in cellForRow method.

I’ve implemented

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"redView":cell.lblText};
    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[redView(10)]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[redView(100)]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                   views:viewsDictionary];

    [cell addConstraints:constraint_H];
    [cell addConstraints:constraint_V];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

and it affected all the rows in the cell and it over-right the constraints.

You can also visit this links for further ref:
http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/ui-design-of-ios-apps-with-autolayout-using-constraints-programmatically/
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Comment: I actually created an IBOUTLET property for the constraint thus there shouldn't be a conflict.